# using mgcrea.ngStrap - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap, angularjs-3rd-party

I am having a discussion with my colleague, who is emphasizing on using

```
$('#createModal').modal('show');
```

instead of the above plugin.

I am creating the modal via code below:

```
$scope.createModal = $modal({    
    scope: $scope,    
    template: '/reports/static/partials/schedule-modal.html',    
    show: true    
})
```

Which apparently does not inherit style sheets of bootstrap, like background color is different, when I create modal in this way.

Could You please kindly advise, why have you preferred using [mgcrea.ngStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) to create the modal and not using:

```
$('#createModal').modal('show');
```

I am unable to explain this to my colleague and I would like to know, so that I could explain the team.

Comment: Sorry, in the question "you" meant programmers who prefer using this plugin!!